# Do Update method needs to be in a form or can just simply inside a button as well?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio

So its just a general question that I would like to know because I'm still new in flutter development. So I just want to know does update method have to be inside a form or it can just simply put inside a button for example like save for profile pages. Heres my profile page. if anyone knew how to implement update inside this page it would be helpful

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_user_profile/model/parking.dart';


class ParkingPage extends StatefulWidget {



  @override
  State<ParkingPage> createState() => _ParkingPageState();
}

class _ParkingPageState extends State<ParkingPage> {
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  Parking loginuser = Parking();
  @override




  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('parkingTech')
    .doc(user!.uid)
    .get()
    .then((value){
      this.loginuser = Parking.fromMap(value.data());
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  // @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF121212),
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF121212),
          elevation: 0.0,
          title: Text('Parking Tech',
            style:TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle:true,
          actions: [
            // Icon(Icons.menu,
            //   color:Colors.amber,
            //   size:40,
            // )
          ]
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children:[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center ,
              children:[
                CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                    radius: 100.0,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('P',
                        style:TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 80,
                          color: Color(0xFF121212),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            Text("Parking time : ${loginuser.name} ",
              style:TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text('00 : 56 : 05',
              style:TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            Text('P15 AED',
              style:TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            Text('On Parking ',
              style:TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15,
                color: Colors.amber,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            Text('End Parking',
              style:TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 12),
            Text('Extend Parking',
              style:TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 12),


          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It will be better if it is in a form because when you try to update again in a different place, writing that code again will cause code duplication.

Comment: can anyone teach me on how to do the update method ?